# PHP SQL Query Fields from Another Table Join

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get a query using fields from 2 tables.
I need to query Table1 but only Table2 has the variable venue_location that I need to query.

Basically I need to count all records on Table1 where Table1.venue_location = $MyVariable.

Here is what I've put together but I believe I need to use Joins for this?

```
Table1

 - venue_id



Table2

 - venue_id,
 - venue_location



SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE table1.venue_id = table2.venue_id and table2.location = '$MyVariable'
```

How can I do a query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the power of join table

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
      JOIN Table2 USING(venue_id)
      WHERE table2.location = '$MyVariable'
```

You can get back the count of rows with `mysqli_num_rows()` in PHP, or change le select by `SELECT COUNT(*) AS nbRow FROM ...` and check of value in `nbRow` column

Answer (score 1):

You can join two tables on venue_id and then group it by `venue_id` where `location` is your `$MyVariable`.

Your final query will look like:

```
SELECT count(table2.venue_id) 
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON table1.venue_id = table2.venue_id
WHERE table2.location = '$MyVariable'
GROUP BY table2.venue_id
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT Table1.venue_id, Table2.venue_location FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.venue_id='$MyVariable';
```